# @StepScope does not work with @ConstructorBinding in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-bean

I tried to make a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean without setters so I used `@ConstructorBinding`. Let's call this class `PropertiesFromYml.java`.

This works fine, bean is created perfectly by the properties from the `yml` file.

The configuration class has the necessary setup:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.my.package") // this is where PropertiesFromYml.java is stored
public class MyConfig
```

**I wanted** to add the `@StepScope` to that `PropertiesFromYml.java` because my SpringBoot application will run scheduled batch jobs, so I don't want to initiate this class, but only when the job needs it.

**BUT:** Unfortunately, the bean is always created during startup. I guess this is because of the `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` annotation on MyConfig.java class. But how can I tell to create the bean only when necessary, like with @StepScope?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration will be created at the start of your application. Instead what you may want to do is split your class into 2. The actual configuration part and the schedule part: `SchedularConfiguration`, `SchedularComponent`. And then inject the configuration into the component.

```java
@StepScope
@Component
class SchedularComponent {

   @Autowired
   SchedularConfiguration config;

}
```

That will allow you to have the scope you want. Usually you wouldn't have a whole other class for configuration of a component (but your requirements may vary) and use directly the `@Value` annotation to select what application property you want: `@Value("${schedular.cron}")`.